# How to rotate a subtree without knowing its parent

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, avl-tree

I'd like to rotate left the subtree rooted at node `N` (see left figure) without manipulating its parent `P`.

```
P             P              P   
 \            |               \
  N           | R              R
 / \          |/              /
L   R         N              N
             /              /
            L              L
```

If I will to it in a function, that takes `N` as an argument:

```
void rotate_left(Node *node);
```

I will end up with a tree presented on the middle figure. The problem is that despite the rotation `P` still points to `N`, not to `R` (left figure). How to make `P` pointing to `R` at the end of rotation if the function `rotate_left()` does not have a pointer to `P`?

I think of three ways of doing this:

1. Let `rotate_left()` takes a reference to pointer to node `N`

   ```
   void rotate_left(Node * &node);
   ```

   Then call `rotate left()`, passing it a right child of `P` (that is
   `N`):

   ```
   rotate_left(P->right_child);
   ```
2. Place object `R` under the memory address of `N` at the end of
   rotation
3. Pass parent P to `rotate_left()`:

   ```
   void rotate_left(Node *parent, Node *child);
   ```

Solutions (2) and (3) don't sound good, and in the solution (1) you need to know parent `P` in function that calls `rotate_left()`.

Comment: You need to know the parent to be able to do this, unless you swap the content instead of the nodes.

Comment: You should know (modify) the parent, because you have to set `R` as it's child, and remove `N` being a child of `P`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 is the best of the three you're suggesting.  It is more or less equivalent to Solution 3.  I'd use that.  It seems to me that everywhere you call `rotate_left` you already know the variable where this pointer is stored (either the parent node, or `root`), so it wouldn't be a problem passing its reference.

Solution 2 (swapping the contents) will invalidate any pointers that already exist outside your tree.  You'll have to be very careful; if there are such pointers, don't use it.  However, this is the only true answer to your question "how to rotate without knowing the parent?".

I suppose you wouldn't want to keep pointers to parent nodes in the tree.  If you're prepared to do that, everything will be much easier.